# how to massage data so that I can use nested ng-repeat with <li>

Tags: angularjs

(please don't update the grammatical /english errors, I dont have enough points and my question will be struck for ever - feel free to comment)

How should i massage the data so that i can load data for following scenario:

On page load, I make a request and for response i get an array of values that are represented in blue lines,

$scope.blueli = [ item1, item2, item3, item4 ];

Then against each blue id values I again want to make requests and grab the value for that specific id, and populate the content in pink `<li>`

I was thinking of using underscore and massage it in such a way 
 [ item1: [i1, i2, i3, i4], item2: [j1, j2, j3, j4 ], item3: [k1, k2, k3, k4 ]];

fyi:  the number of values for blue and for pink would be dynamic.

[image]

```
<div class="row">
                <ul>
                    <li class="no-bullet-li li-12" ng-repeat="plan in json">
                        {{plan.name}}
                    <ul>
                         <li class="no-bullet-li li-8" ng-repat="item in plan.list">{{item}}
                         {{plan.list}}
                            soemthing comes here 2
                        </li>
                    </ul> 
                    </li>


                </ul>
            </div>
```

//controller

Lets say in the controller I massaged the data and get the end result like below.

```
           $scope.json=[
            {"name":"John", "list":["plan1", "plan2", "plan3"]}, 
            {"name":"Anna", "list":["plan1", "plan2", "plan3"]}, 
            {"name":"Peter", "list":["plan1", "plan2", "plan3"]}, 
           ];
```

[image: output]

Issues:
1) Why doesnt it lists seperate pink li-s for each value in the list. 

2) The li tags aren't seperate nicely in html.

Comment: "1) Why doesn't it list separate pink li-s for each value in the list."

You mean why doesn't it show `<li>plan1</li><li>plan2</li>...` then its because you are using `{{plan.list}}` rather than `{{item}}`

Comment: "The li tags aren't separate nicely in html."

This is because you are wrapping the pink li inside the blue li. You would want something like `<ul><li><div class="blue">John</div><ul><li><div class="pink">plan1</div></li></ul></li></ul>`

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
var blueItems = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];
var bluePinkItems = [];

function loadPinkItems(id) {
  // Use the id to get the pink items
  // If this is async then you'll need to do a callback
  return [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
}

angular.forEach(blueItems, function(item) {
  bluePinkItems[item] = loadPinkItems(item);
});

// This ensures angular doesn't render until all the data is loaded
// If this is async and you want to load after each request then you can put it in the loop
$scope.data = bluePinkItems;

/*
$scope.data = {
  item1: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  item2: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
  item3: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
};
*/
```

Then the html would look like

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="(blueItem,pinkItems) key in data">
    {{blueItem}}
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="pinkItem in pinkItems">
        {{pinkItem}}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

or you could use arrays and an index which is what I prefer

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="blueItem key in blueItems">
    {{blueItem}}
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="pinkItem in bluePinkItems[blueItem]">
        {{pinkItem}}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```